# Angular 5 - Circular Dependency detected

Tags: angular5

I have a module A  _ with many differents components _ which is imported in an other module B. And I need now to use component of module B in a component of module A, but I can't import it because it cause a kind of infinite loop of dependencies.I get the error "Circular dependency detected" . Is anyone could help me??